# Looping Oracle Data Readers returns inconsistent results

Tags: c#, oracle, datareader

I have a problem. I have a loop set up for statistical analysis of two functions. The first time through the loop everything is fine in both functions. The second time through the loop the second function doesn't return any results.

I don't understand why the first time through the loops i get results from the dataReader and every subsequent time through i get nothing (`datareader.hasRows == false`)

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Below is a synopsis of the code for the looping structure and the second function (that is failing)

```
startDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        endDate = new DateTime(2010, j, 1);
        schedule = new Schedule();
        scheduleXml = string.Empty;

        ISession newSession = session.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        scheduleXml = GetScheduleXml(startDate, endDate, locationIds, newSession);
        schedule = GetSchedule(schedule, startDate, endDate, locationIds, newSession);
        newSession.Close();
    }
}

public static Schedule GetSchedule(Schedule schedule, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int locationIds, ISession session)
{
    string sqlGetActivitiesTreatmentsRegimens = // Custom SQL Select Statement (I have verified it returns results)
    using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sqlGetActivitiesTreatmentsRegimens, (OracleConnection)session.Connection))
    {
        try
        {
            OracleParameter plantIdParam = comm.CreateParameter();
            plantIdParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            plantIdParam.Value = plantId;
            comm.Parameters.Add(plantIdParam);

            OracleParameter startDateParam = comm.CreateParameter();
            startDateParam.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
            startDateParam.Value = startDate;
            comm.Parameters.Add(startDateParam);

            OracleParameter endDateParam = comm.CreateParameter();
            endDateParam.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
            endDateParam.Value = endDate;
            comm.Parameters.Add(endDateParam);

            using(OracleDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    // does stuff here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Source:GetRegimensEx:" + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
    return new Schedule();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the code you posted is fine apart from the obvious syntax errors. The error is either in `GetScheduleXml` or in the implementation of the class that implements `ISession`.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Daniel. Also, you use session.Connection in the using statement, but the parameter in the method signature is newSession.

The DataReader is in a using, so that handles the closing. No need for an extra .Close() call.

Comment: I was thinking the same about the parameter, but if the first loop iteration works, then that shouldn't be it?

Comment: I generally agree, but because the functions are static and we cannot see what GetScheduleXml or the class that implements ISession are doing to static variables, we don't know.

Comment: hmmmm... that gives me a couple of ideas. I'll look into how the ISession is implemented.
In essences GetScheduleXml does is read from a stored procedure and return an xml string that is based on the output from the stored procedure.

Comment: Also the newSession vs session variables was a typo when i was extracting the code into a simpler format.

Comment: any luck? I would recommend wrapping the "using(OracleCommand comm.." with a "using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString){}". This will let the function doing the database calls handle the connection (including the close and dispose), and as long as you are using connection pooling, you won't see any performance hit. This way you won't need to worry about maintaining connection state between iterations of the loop.